# Inconsistent logarithm and rounding

Tags: java, double, rounding, logarithm, significance

Recently while developing a calculator to simplify a game (reactoridle), I ran into one persistent problem. The problem was that when an input number in the GUI was changed into a number between certain boundaries it would immediately snap back to the number below it when pressing enter, sometimes it would even repeat if you pressed enter again.

I figured that one part of the code was somehow inconsistent with another piece, even though the maths behind it were solid.

The first piece of code calculates the heat produced by heat cells, the second recalculates the upgrades required in each component to process that heat.
So say the upgrade you're at right now is right at the boundary of the code working and conflicting, if you then increment the upgrade, it will immediately snap back. As the first piece of code calculates the heat, and the second decides that you could do with one less upgrade to still achieve that heat.

The relevant bits of code are:

```
double insulationMultiplier = 1 + insulationPerCell * (insulationUpgrades + 1) * INSULATION_HEAT_MODIFIER;
            double upgradeMultiplier = Math.pow(Cell.HEAT_MULTIPLIER, cellUpgrades);
            this.heat = cells * insulationMultiplier * upgradeMultiplier * cell.heat * (1 + 0x4p-50d); //???
                                                                                        //avoid trouble when calculating cellUpgrades

            this.calculate(START_FROM_HEAT);
```

```
double insulationMultiplier = 1 + insulationPerCell * (insulationUpgrades + 1) * INSULATION_HEAT_MODIFIER; 
            double circulatorMultiplier = circulators ? CIRCULATOR_HEAT_MODIFIER * Math.pow(CIRCULATOR_HEAT_MULTIPLIER, circulatorUpgrades) : 1;

            cellUpgrades = (int) ((Math.log(this.heat) - Math.log(insulationMultiplier * cells * cell.heat)) / Math.log(Cell.HEAT_MULTIPLIER));
```

As you can see, I solved the problem by multiplying the heat calculated in the first part by `1 + 0x4p-50d`, this is so that the heat is adjusted just enough to prevent the second part of the algorithm from rounding the upgrade down again and as small as possible to avoid displaying a much different heat value.

The same problem occurs in a parallel piece of code, relevant to the two other components, however on a much larger scale, so that it jumps down multiple numbers at once. I'd prefer not solving it the same way as I've done for the first component, as that would likely collide with other things in turn.

Is there a more rigorous so to speak way to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you are not working at the limits of the precision of `double`, if you are you should use a different strategy. Either use BigDecimal or use formula which don't have this issue.

Comment: My guess is that `* (1 + 0x4p-50d)` works as a fudge factor for a small representation error. I suggest storing the `logOfHeat` instead of the `heat` value.